# Identity for $\gamma$ and proving the identity in different ways .

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof, harmonic-numbers

Following is the [well know result](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) that connects *Harmonic number* with *binomial coefficients*,
$$\color{red}{H_n}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}{n\choose k}$$

This motivates me and I  came to find the following identity for *Euler-Mascheroni constant*, $\gamma$.

> $$\lim_{j\to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^{j}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1} \color{red}{H_k}{n\choose k}-\ln m\right)\frac{1}{j}=\gamma$$

**My solution**
Due to *Euler* we have that $$H_k=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}dx$$ and using  the result  we observe that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1} H_k{n\choose k}=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}\right)\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{1}{n\choose k}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1+(1-x)^k-1}{1-x}dx=\int_0^1 (1-x)^{n-1}dx =\frac{1}{n}$$ Here we make the use of result $$\small{ \sum_{\color{green}{k=0}}^{n}(-1)^k{n\choose k} =0,\;\;\sum_{\color{green}{k=0}}^n(-1)^{k+1}{n\choose k}x^{k}=(1-x)^n}$$ and thus we have $$\lim_{j\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{j}\left(\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{n}-\ln m\right)\frac{1}{j}=\lim_{j\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{j}\left(H_m-\ln  m\right)\frac{1}{j}\cdots(1)$$  By *Stolz- Cesaro theorem*  result $(1)$  it directly follows $$\displaystyle \lim_{j\to \infty} (H_{j+1}-\ln(j+1))=\gamma$$
Result can be also be proved in the following manner. $$\lim_{j\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{j}\left(H_m-\ln m\right) =\lim_{j\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^j\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{i}-\ln m \right)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(\sum_{m=1}^j\frac{j-m+1}{m}-\ln\ j!\right)\frac{1}{j}$$ Using the Stirling approximation of $\ln j!= j\ln j- j+O(\ln j)$ we have then $$\lim_{j\to \infty}\left(H_j-\ln j\right)=\gamma$$
As the claimed to found to be true. So, I'm curious to  know if we can prove  the  result in different way/s than presentated here.How can we prove the result in others ways?

Thank you